# Appending the selected value to input field using ionic2 /angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to append the selected value to input field using angular2/ionic2. I tried in the following way but it is appending in the following way:

[image]

But the actual requirement is like this:
**fdfdfdf@hdfc** or **fdfdfd@icici**

### view

```
<ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Bank Name</ion-label>
        <ion-select [formControl]="bank" (ionChange)="bankChange($event)">
          <ion-option value="HDFC">HDFC</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="ICICI">ICICI</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

### typescript

```
export class AddAccountPage {
  addAccountForm: ControlGroup;
  vaddr: AbstractControl;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.addAccountForm = fb.group({  
      'vaddr': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    });    
    this.vaddr = this.addAccountForm.controls['vaddr'];     
  }

  bankChange(val){
   (this.vaddr as Control).updateValue(this.vaddr.value +'@'+ val);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem in the following way,

```
if(this.vaddr.value.indexOf('@') > -1){
   (this.vaddr as Control).updateValue(this.vaddr.value.split("@")[0]);  
}
```